# Last inserted value on SQL Server with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have this code that will insert some data on my table and i need to get the last inserted ID that is my PK.

```
    $serverName     = "MyServer";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MyBD", "UID"=>"MyUser", "PWD"=>"MyPass");
    $conn           = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn )
    {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $nome     = $_POST["nome"];
    $email    = $_POST["email"];
    $telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
    $unidade  = $_POST["unidade"];

    //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
    $query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Participante] ([nome],[email],[telefone],[unidadeCE],[dataCadastro]) VALUES ('" . $nome . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $telefone . "', '" . $unidade . "', (getdate())); SELECT @@IDENTITY";

    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

    var_dump($result);

    //close the connection
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

I have already tried the SELECT `@@IDENTITY` but it only returns `resource(4) of type (SQL Server Statement)`

Comment: use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: @Jordy, sorry i didn't find that ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Participante] ([nome],[email],[telefone],[unidadeCE],[dataCadastro]) VALUES ('" . $nome . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $telefone . "', '" . $unidade . "', (getdate())); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
$resource=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $arrParams); 
sqlsrv_next_result($resource); 
sqlsrv_fetch($resource); 
echo sqlsrv_get_field($resource, 0);
```

[Reference:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php#104263)

Comment: @Terkhos, if my answer worked for you, please accept it as solution.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that !

Answer (score -1):

This works :

```
select last_insert_id() as last_id
```